# Failed to deploy Heroku app. ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /app/.heroku/python/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize;

Tags: python, django, heroku

These are errors I am getting, I can't post the entire log because of the character limit sorry.

```
         Building wheel for psycopg2 (setup.py): started
         Building wheel for psycopg2 (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
         ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
          command: /app/.heroku/python/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-mxd65ubh/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-mxd65ubh/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-mfz2er96
              cwd: /tmp/pip-install-mxd65ubh/psycopg2/
```

Second Error:

```
         psycopg/psycopgmodule.c: In function ‘psyco_is_main_interp’:
         psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:689:18: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘PyInterpreterState’ {aka ‘struct _is’}
           689 |     while (interp->next)
               |                  ^~
         error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
         ----------------------------------------
         ERROR: Failed building wheel for psycopg2
         Running setup.py clean for psycopg2
       Successfully built Pillow
       Failed to build psycopg2
       Installing collected packages: docutils, jmespath, six, python-dateutil, urllib3, botocore, s3transfer, boto3, certifi, chardet, dj-database-url, pytz, Django, django-crispy-forms, whitenoise, psycopg2, django-heroku, django-storages, gunicorn, idna, Pillow, requests
           Running setup.py install for psycopg2: started
           Running setup.py install for psycopg2: finished with status 'error'
```

Third Error:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
                command: /app/.heroku/python/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-mxd65ubh/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-mxd65ubh/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-08ru_8_3/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /app/.heroku/python/include/python3.9/psycopg2
                    cwd: /tmp/pip-install-mxd65ubh/psycopg2/
             
               psycopg/psycopgmodule.c: In function ‘psyco_is_main_interp’:
               psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:689:18: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘PyInterpreterState’ {aka ‘struct _is’}
                 689 |     while (interp->next)
                     |                  ^~
               error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
               ----------------------------------------
           ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /app/.heroku/python/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-mxd65ubh/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-mxd65ubh/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-08ru_8_3/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /app/.heroku/python/include/python3.9/psycopg2 Check the logs for full command output.
     !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
     !     Push failed
```

> **This is my requirements.txt file**
> boto3==1.9.96
> botocore==1.12.96
> certifi==2018.10.15
> chardet==3.0.4
> dj-database-url==0.5.0
> Django==2.1
> django-crispy-forms==1.7.2
> django-heroku==0.3.1
> django-storages==1.7.1
> docutils==0.14
> gunicorn==19.9.0
> idna==2.7
> jmespath==0.9.3
> Pillow==5.2.0
> psycopg2==2.7.7
> python-dateutil==2.8.0
> pytz==2018.5
> requests==2.19.1
> s3transfer==0.2.0
> six==1.12.0
> urllib3==1.23
> whitenoise==4.1.2

Answer (score 0):

Try to install psycopg2-binary with `pip install psycopg2-binary` instead of psycopg2.

Comment: Should I add that to requirements.txt? If not then I have already installed psycopg2-binary still the same issue

Comment: Yes, add it to requirements.txt also